# Change method's Behavior from attribute

Tags: c#

I want to change Behavior of method from attribute.
Consider this Pseudocode:

```
public class CheckHoliday : System.Attribute
{
    //Here I want exit from consumer method if today is holiday 
}

public class TestClass{

    [CheckHoliday]
    public void TestMethod(){

    }
}
```

I dont want use aspect oriented.

Comment: I don't think this is not possible without any kind of pre-compiler like PostSharp is doing it. You maybe can change the IL-Code of the method, but I am not sure if this applicaple.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but the methods in your attribute won't be automatically called when the method that has the attribute runs. You'll need to do it manually.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you elaborate on what exactly it is you want, and preferably also why? What is the bigger picture here?

Comment: Why specifically an attribute, and why not aspect-oriented?  Using attributes for this purpose is a perfect fit for aspect-oriented programming.  If you don't want to use something like PostSharp, then your best bet is to explicitly compose the behavior you want using decorators or higher-order functions.

Comment: attributes are only metadata which means that an attribute can't do anything...
you will need to have an additional  piece of code that will read that attribute using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

The question wasn't clear for me also, but if this is what you want to achieve there is a workaround with global variable. Although it does nothing but pre-computes the holiday.

```
//Declare a global variable
public Boolean IsHoliday = false;

//Attribute 
public class CheckHoliday : System.Attribute
{
    //Here I want exit from consumer method if today is holiday ?
    //this ain't possible 
    public CheckHoliday()
    {
        //if  today is holiday  make IsHoliday= true based on logic
        IsHoliday= true;
        //Else keep it false
    }

}

public class TestClass
{
    [CheckHoliday]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
       //Here you can exit  if today is holiday
        if (IsHoliday)
            return;

        //Else Method Logic here

    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder why the downvote was cast. I agree that this is really shitty code that should never make it into production, but it answers OPs question. I guess the Correct(tm) answer would be "don't" though.

Answer (score 0):

What about this, not elegant, but would change behaviour based on whether the method had the attribute...

```
namespace Behave
{
    using System;
    using System.Reflection;

    public class CheckHolidayAttribute : Attribute { }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SomeAction();
            Console.Read();
        }

        //[CheckHoliday] // uncomment this to see what happens
        public static void SomeAction()
        {
            if(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().GetCustomAttribute<CheckHolidayAttribute>() != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Has attr");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Does not have attr");
            }
        }
    }
}
```